How to round Geodesic distances to the nearest meter
I have calculated the distances between a large number of nodes to give weights to the edges in a network that I'm building. Now that I'm trying to graph the network to display it, it comes out very messy because all the distances are going to 5/6+ decimal places and running over into the names of the nodes and it becomes unreadable.
I've tried using the round function with roung(g,3) where g is the geodesic distance between some two nodes but get "TypeError: type geodesic doesn't define round method". For constructing my graph I've tried multiple layouts and spring/fruchterman reingold layouts work the best but it still looks like a mess because of all the distance/weight numbers being so long. I've also tried using
weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(map,'distance') arr = np.array(list(weight.values())) K=3 rounded=np.round(arr,K)
but when I do this I get "AttributeError: 'geodesic' object has no attribute 'rint'". If there's a way to either round these distances down or have nx.draw() function only display the first x amount of numbers that would be perfect.

The datatype is incompatible with the numpy function you are calling, but can you cast the datatype to float and then try rounding?
I have some python code that labels distances on an image and do the decimal rounding with text = f"{data_list[i]:0,.3f}" where data_list is a list of floats.
import numpy as np
# convert to float
arr.astype(np.float32)
K=3
rounded=np.round(arr,K)


When I try using distances.astype where distances is what I'm working with the distance values in it I get 'dict' object has no attribute 'astype'. My dict looks like { (x,y)  : Distance(Value of distance) , ......} layout wise if that helps at all

Is it possible the question and solution here would work for this objective?
